# Webpage stops to respond after selecting a date using webdriver click updated

Tags: selenium-webdriver

we have a webpage with 2 date calender one is a current date the other is referencedate which autoupdates itself to display a day less than the current date.

issue-After selecting a date from a calender using webdriver click the other
calender which had to update the date automatically, does not update anymore.

The same actions if performed manually works. 
Has anybody faced a similiar issue, this has become a blocker since with the autoupdate not working the entire application workflow fails.

removed sensitive data

```
package pages;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.SendKeysAction;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.SeleniumMutator;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.SeleniumSelect;

import utils.Waitutils;

public class CalenderPage {

WebDriver driver;
  static WebDriverWait wait;

    public CalenderPage (WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public  void cobDatepick(String date){

        int count=0;



         WebElement cob =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainview']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/options-panel-directive/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/date-picker/div[2]/div/span"));

         cob.click();

        WebElement mLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@id,'datepicker')]"));


        String date_dd_MM_yyyy[] = (date.split(" ")[0]).split("/");

        int yearDiff = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - Integer.parseInt(date_dd_MM_yyyy[2]);

        mLink.click();


        WebElement pLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainview']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/options-panel-directive/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/date-picker/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/table/thead/tr[1]/th[1]/button/i"));


        if(yearDiff>0){

                    for(int i=0;i<yearDiff;i++){

                         pLink.click();


                    }


           }

        List<WebElement> months1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainview']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/options-panel-directive/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/date-picker/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td"));


           months1.get(Integer.parseInt(date_dd_MM_yyyy[1])-1).click();

        List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainview']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/options-panel-directive/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/date-picker/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/table/tbody/tr//td"));

        int total_nodes = dates.size();

        for(int i=0; i<total_nodes; i++)
        {
           String dat = dates.get(i).getText();

           if(dat.equals(date_dd_MM_yyyy[0])&& count>0)
           {                   
                 dates.get(i).click();
                 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                 js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('date-picker-to').setAttribute('value', '30/06/2016');");




           }

           if(dat.equals(date_dd_MM_yyyy[0]))
           {
               count++;
           }

        }



   }
```

}

The above class is called in the testscript

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws Exception{

     driver = new AppDriver("ie").getDriver();
     driver.get("https://xyz");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    onCalenderPage = new CalenderPage (driver);

    Waitutils.waitforCompletion(9000L);

}
@Test
public void test(){ 

    onCalenderPage.cobDatepick("30/06/2016");

}
```

Comment: It is very hard to help without code to look at. Can you remove the sensitive data or create a separate sample to show us the issue.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the quick reply. i have updated the code for your reference